# how to restrict a user from using application to just one tab, device or windows at a time?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is how i am doing right now

**my middleware.py**

```
class MySessionMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
       
        response = self.get_response(request)
       
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user, _ = LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)   
            print(user)
            if not request.session.session_key:
                request.session.save()
            prev_session_key = user.session_key
            if prev_session_key:
                if prev_session_key != request.session.session_key:
                    return JsonResponse("you already have a active session kindly logout from that", 
                            status=400, safe=False)
            user.session_key = request.session.session_key
            user.save()
       
        return response
```

**my models.py**

```
class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='logged_in_user', on_delete =models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
```

**my signals.py**

```
@receiver(user_logged_in)
def when_user_logs_in(sender,  user, request, **kwargs):
    print('user_logs_signal is called')
    LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('user'))

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def when_user_logs_out(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print('user logs out signal iscalled')
    LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('user')).delete()
```

**my errors**

- my signals are not firing , i am currently testing the application
  via postman and using token based authentication, they are not firing
  thats why i am creating object inside middlware
- While using postman LoggedInUser object session key and request.session session key always comes out to be same

**my doubts**

- I know when a user signs up from different tab, window a new session key is generated but what are the other scenarios when a new session key is generated .
- If the issues that i am facing is because i am using postman then how can i test the application in browser as i need to send the authorization header in it
- Why my signals are not firing despite i have imported them in apps.py is this also the reason of use of postman

Please help me and clear my doubts, i have been stuck here since one week and not getting a solution to my problems
any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the user to a single tab/window? It will be almost impossible to restrict a user to a single tab/window since the same cookies and headers will be sent in every request

Comment: Oh, so can you please tell how to delete previous user sessions or logout  from previous tab/window  if he tries to hit api  not from the same tab

Comment: No, it's pretty much impossible to tell if a request is coming from a different tab. What you are looking for is not feasible

Comment: I think in the browser it will be very hard so I think you need to use a more complex model like in your HTML user token generated  if the user changes the tab you will generate a new token and send this token to the backend when it changes you can expire the last token

Comment: I want a functionality like whatsapp web , like in it a user cannot open application in two different windows

Comment: how can i achieve that

Comment: @DhruvSinghal whatsapp web uses a JS webworker that detects if multiple tabs are accessing it. You can replicate this functionality by writing your own JS that does the same thing

Comment: ok understood can you please also answer my doubt on Django sessions like when a new session key is generated for a particular user

Comment: @DhruvSinghal I'm not sure what your doubt is, when a user logs in they get a new session

Comment: You could consider counting currently opened windows/tabs in browser's local storage (task for Javascript rather than for Django). It has some limitations, though, eg. it won't work for separate devices nor separate browser applications.

Comment: @IainShelvington i want to ask like i am using token Based authentication so whenever i make a request with a same authorization header session is same otherwise new session has to be created